# How can I integrate manatee works barcode scanner in a stacklayout?

Tags: c#, xamarin, manateeworks

I've got an issue of how can I integrate the manatee barcode scanner within my stacklayout with specific measurement... Here's a picture of my code...

[image]

And here's my code actual code... Please help me out...

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout x:Name="layoutWrapper" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ActivityIndicator Color="{StaticResource headerColor}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <Grid x:Name="scannerWrapper" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource not}" >
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <StackLayout HeightRequest="20"></StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Label TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{i18n:Translate ScanInventoryLbl}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout HeightRequest="40"></StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="280" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="5" Orientation="Horizontal"></StackLayout>
                    <Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                    <Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <StackLayout x:Name="ipInputLabel" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="5" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{i18n:Translate NoQRLbl}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                        <Label x:Name="versionAppLabel" FontSize="14" TextColor="#1976D2" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout HeightRequest="20"></StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ViewRenderer and include that View in your page.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view/

Here in this app https://github.com/manateeworks/xamarin-shopping-cart-demo-app scanner is implemented as page. Make changes and convert PageRenderer to ViewRenderer.

Also use scanner.ScanInView in native ViewRenderer instead of scanner.ScanWithCallback. Here is part of code from Droid native ViewRenderer

```js
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ManateeShoppingCart.CameraPreview), typeof(ManateeShoppingCart.Droid.ScanPageRenderer))]
namespace ManateeShoppingCart.Droid
{
    public class ScanPageRenderer : ViewRenderer, IScanSuccessCallback
    {
        Scanner scanner;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            scanner = new Scanner(Forms.Context);
            scanner.setInterfaceOrientation("All");
            scanner.closeScannerOnDecode = false;

            customDecoderInit();

            double screenHeight = App.Current.MainPage.Height > App.Current.MainPage.Width ? App.Current.MainPage.Height : App.Current.MainPage.Width;
            double screenWidth = App.Current.MainPage.Height < App.Current.MainPage.Width ? App.Current.MainPage.Height : App.Current.MainPage.Width; ;

            float preivewX = (float)((CameraPreview)Element).CameraPreviewX;
            float preivewY = (float)((CameraPreview)Element).CameraPreviewY;
            float previewWidth = (float)((CameraPreview)Element).CameraPreviewWidth;
            float previewHeight = (float)((CameraPreview)Element).CameraPreviewHeight;

            scanner.ScanInView(this, new RectangleF((float)(preivewX / screenWidth) * 100, (float)(preivewY / screenHeight) * 100, (float)(previewWidth / screenWidth) * 100, (float)(previewHeight / screenHeight) * 100));
        }
```

Comment: Yeah, I have tried using this way but it does not work. I tried modifying some editing options in it's sample app's renderer page yet there's no option there to edit the window size, except for the scanning area. Any more suggestions? Thanks for the reply...

Comment: And how should I call the result directly without creating void `IScanSuccessCallback.barcodeDetected(MWResult result)` ?

Comment: You cant, with scanner.ScanInView the only way to get result is with callback.

Comment: But if I insert a `scanner.Scan();` or `scanner.ScanWithCallback(this);`, it'll only becomes black with those red rectangular lines. As far as I have investigated the code, the only way to call the ISScanSuccessCallback is using `scanner.ScanWithCallback(this);`.

Comment: Can you please open ticket on https://manateeworks.com/tickets/submit_ticket for your issue.

Comment: Well, yeah. I've done it, yet no replies. Anyway, thanks for the response.

Comment: Text me ticket ID